# How to save variables & stop variables from being overwritten in R?

Tags: r

So I have a bunch of functions that save the column numbers of my data. So for example, my data looks something like:

```
>MergedData
[[1]]
Date      EUR.HIGH EUR.LOW EUR.CLOSE EUR.OPEN EUR.LAST
01/01/16  1.00      1.00       1.25      1.30     1.24

[[2]]
Date    AUD.HIGH AUD.LOW AUD.CLOSE AUD.OPEN AUD.LAST
01/01/16  1.00      1.00       1.25      1.30     1.24
```

I have 29 of the above currencies. So in this case, MergedData[[1]] will return all of my Euro prices, and so on for 29 currencies.

I also have a function in R that calculates the variables and saves the numbers 1 to 29 that correspond with the currencies. This code calculates values in the first row of my data, i.e:

```
trending <- intersect(which(!ma.sig[1,]==0), which(!pricebreak[1,]==0))
```

which returns something like:

```
>sig.nt 
[1] 1 2 5...
```

And so I can use this to pull up 'trending' currencies via a for() function:

```
for (i in length(sig.nt){
MergedData[[i]]
...misc. code for calculations of trending currencies...
}
```

I want to be able to 'save' my trending currencies for future references and calculations. The problem is sig.nt variable changes with every new row. I was thinking of using the lockBinding command:

```
sig.exist <- sig.nt #saves existing trend
lockBinding('curexist', .GlobalEnv)
```

But wouldn't this still get overwritten everytime I run my script? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Write it out to a file with `Sys.Date()` as part of the filename.

Comment: By the way, you can/should reshape your data and save currency abbreviations instead of col numbers. Col numbers will become a real pain if/when you add/remove/rearrange currencies.

Comment: @Gregor I'll try my hand at this, thanks!

Comment: @Frank Good point. I actually have a code that, after reading my Excel file into R, reshapes the data into MergedData[[i]] with i corresponding to a currency variable.  It's currently going by currency name, but I'm trying to figure out a way if I can group it by high,low,close,open since I might add in more than just currency variables. Thanks though!